# How to handle events for icon tray in windows using C#

Tags: c#, windows, system-tray

Can any body tell me how to handle events for System tray in windows.

I mean, when some body clicks on the system tray icon then I want to check whether to enable the application or not. Is there any way to capture events corresponding to system tray click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a .NET Forms Application the System Tray control { NotifyIcon } provides following Events to check what you want to achieve:

- Click
- DoubleClick
- MouseClick
- MouseDoubleClick

You can put the logic into these event handlers.

I hope this one helps out!

Comment: Yea, I tried it, but the problem is that event will be fired only when the application icon is clicked in icon bar, but I want to handle click on any of the application in the icon bar, and check whether to allow that application to focus or not.
Any comments?

Comment: Oh! Then you want to handle all behaviors in the icon tray, no matter where you click? Right? Let me see if I can find something!

Answer (score 1):

[CodeProject about NotifyIcon](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/notifyiconcontrol20.aspx)
[MSDN about NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984200(VS.71).aspx)

### NotifyIcon class events:

**Click**   *Occurs when the user clicks the icon in the status area.*
**DoubleClick** *Occurs when the user double-clicks the icon in the status notification area of the taskbar.*
**MouseDown**   *Occurs when the user presses the mouse button while the pointer is over the icon in the status notification area of the taskbar.*
**MouseMove**   *Occurs when the user moves the mouse while the pointer is over the icon in the status notification area of the taskbar.*
**MouseUp** *Occurs when the user releases the mouse button while the pointer is over the icon in the status notification area of the taskbar.*